# Writing File in binary & Hex with bit manipulation

Tags: c++, qt, binary, hex

According to my criteria i need to store data in a long HEX-line.

The problem comes when certain bits of a byte need to be a certain value

EXAMPLE

```
      Field Name | Size
          A      |  2-Bytes
          B      |  4-Bytes
          C      |  1-Bytes
```

& further within  Field A of 2 bytes
the 1st 2 bits must represent "type"(either 01 or 10)
& the next 14 bits must represent an integer(Location of type)

```
      #--------#-----------------------#
      |  TYPE  |       Location        |
      #--------#-----------------------#
        2-bits          14-bits
      ***********************************> Total 2 bytes
```

Similar process for other fields

**How do i store data in a fixed field size
with the required starting bits representing the type**

If possible please provide me with a simple example
of, let's say:

```
        Type = 01
      & Location = 412
```

Stored in hex format of size 2 bytes

This is in a C++ project that uses Qt, so you can use Qt APIs.

Comment: big or little endian?

Comment: Look up bitwise operators.

Comment: low order -> least significant bits of byte... little endian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question has nothing to do with Qt, c++ or any other language. All languages will handle this in pretty much the same way.

If you're concerned with specific bits in a variable, you need to use the bitwise operators.

Your specific example shows that your variable is 2 bytes (16 bits) so you're most likely using an `unsigned short int`. In Qt, this has been `typedef`ed as `quint16`

To get the bits for the `Type` and `Location` data, you would apply the bitwise operators like so:

```
quint16 data;
...
Type type = static_cast<Type>((data & 0xC000) >> 14); // assuming Type is an enum
int location = data & 0x3FFF;
```

To store the bits in a single integer value, you would do the reverse the process:

```
Type type;
int location;
...
quint16 data = static_cast<int>(type) & 0xFF << 14;
data += location & 0x3FFF;
```